# Xamarin's forms Date Picker android icon a bit out of way

Tags: xamarin.forms

I am trying to place a synfcusion button that has a calendar image near a xarmain forms entry box.

But its a bit out of alignment what I have tried so far is.

```
<Label Text="Please select a start date below"></Label>
 <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
 <Entry x:Name="txtDateStartEntry" WidthRequest="200" ></Entry>
 <syncfusion:SfButton x:Name="btnPickStartDate" CornerRadius="10"  HorizontalTextAlignment="Start" ShowIcon="True" Clicked="btnPickStartDate_Clicked"  FontSize="24" BorderThickness="2" TextColor="White"  BackgroundColor="White"  Text="..."  >
<syncfusion:SfButton.Content>
  <Grid ColumnDefinitions="Auto, *, Auto"  ColumnSpacing="16" Padding="16">
  <Image Grid.Column="1" HorizontalOptions="End" WidthRequest="30" HeightRequest="30" Source="cal16.png" VerticalOptions="End"/>
   </Grid>
  </syncfusion:SfButton.Content>
  </syncfusion:SfButton>
</StackLayout>
```

What I have eneded up with is this.

[image]

As you can see its a bit far away from the entry field and doesnt look like it belongs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using Syncfusion, you should make use of [SfTextInputLayout](https://help.syncfusion.com/xamarin/text-input-layout/custom-icons#trailing--view) which provides leading/trailing view functionality for the express purpose of adding descriptive iconography to an input view.

Code example assumes importing the following `xmlns`:

```
xmlns:sftl="clr-namespace:Syncfusion.XForms.TextInputLayout;assembly=Syncfusion.Core.XForms"
```

```cs
<sftl:SfTextInputLayout TrailingViewPosition="Inside">
  <Entry x:Name="txtDateStartEntry" WidthRequest="200" />
  <sftl:SfTextInputLayout.TrailingView>
    <Image HeightRequest="30" Source="cal16.png">
      <Image.GestureRecognizers>
        <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="btnPickStartDate_Clicked" />
      </Image.GestureRecognizers>
    </Image>
  <sftl:SfTextInputLayout.TrailingView>
</sftl:SfTextInputLayout>
```

Note: when using LeadingView or TrailingView, it's recommended to not assign a Width value as Syncfusion will calculate the width based on the height you request to maintain aspect ratio of the specified view. Therefore I have intentionally excluded `HeightRequest` from the `Image`.

Comment: Yes but a button gives me a click event how would I do click on the text input ?

Comment: Use a [TapGestureRecognizer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/gestures/tap). I'll update my answer to include that.

Comment: Syncfusion is cool they give us so many free components in community

Comment: What would be the best height to have the icon 16 looks a tad small whats normal height of a text entry widget

Comment: @csharpdude77 I use 16 in my app. I'd play around with it and find what looks best for yours :)